# How to check for blank fields in input json data in python?

Tags: python, json, parsing, python-2.7, python-3.x

Suppose in my python below function, i am getting the json feeds like below

```
 def mapper_1(self, key, line):
  j_feed = json.loads(line)
  unicoded = j_feed[u'category_description'].encode("utf-8")
  cn = j_feed[u'categoryname']
  location = j_feed[u'location']
```

How to check if there is any blank fields for data in categoryname/categorydescription/location from the input.json.

Comment: `if str.strip()` or `if str is None` ?

Answer (score 0):

Say you are unsure of your fields, you can use `.get` and provide it a default sentinel value

```
fields = ['categoryname', 'categorydescription', 'location']

for field in fields:
    print j_feed.get(field, "not set!")
```